# ArduinoJSON define as extern

Tags: json

My sketch contains 2 `.h` files. one defines

on 1st `.h` file:

```
#define JSON_SIZE_IOT 400
#define JSON_SIZE_SKETCH 300
StaticJsonDocument<JSON_SIZE_IOT> paramJSON;
StaticJsonDocument<JSON_SIZE_SKETCH> sketchJSON;
```

and other need to define `paramJSON` and `sketchJSON` as `extern`

on 2nd `.h` file:

```
extern JsonDocument paramJSON;
extern JsonDocument paramJSON;
```

but I get this error:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'ArduinoJson6172_91::StaticJsonDocument<400u> paramJSON'
 StaticJsonDocument<JSON_SIZE_IOT> paramJSON;
```

....

```
: previous declaration as 'ArduinoJson6172_91::JsonDocument paramJSON'
 extern JsonDocument paramJSON;
```

Comment: please look at the code snippets that you posted ... the problem appears to be obvious ... the copy'n'paste bug strikes again

Comment: @jsotola do you mean `JsonDocument` instead `StaticJsonDocument`? it does not work either way

Comment: no ... you made a duplicate declaration

Comment: @jsotola See edit which code snippet belong to which .h file ( unless I don't understand why it is a duplicate )

Comment: don't do variable definitions in h file which is included in multiple translation units

Comment: @Juraj I understand what you say, it can be done, but it is very not clear way. Does it mean that it is impossible to do so ?

Comment: a variable definition should always be in cpp. in h only if you know what you are doing. but in to extern: it must be the same type including the template types.

Comment: @Juraj Thank you. My `.h` file sums each functionality used in sketch. BTW, there is no `.cpp` in my case, only `.ino` and `.h`'s. How would you have done it if there was a `.cpp` file ?

Comment: then put it in ino or add a cpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `extern` the whole definition has to match the "master" definition.

So if you have:

```cpp
StaticJsonDocument<JSON_SIZE_IOT> paramJSON;
```

then you `extern` has to be:

```cpp
extern StaticJsonDocument<JSON_SIZE_IOT> paramJSON;
```

Of course you have to make sure your `JSON_SIZE_IOT` is the same for both - so it's best if that comes from a common source.

This is known as *explicit instantiation declaration* and you can read more about it in the [Class template C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Comment: Doesn't `StaticJsonDocument` a template ? that is why I used `JsonDocument `. Since `JSON_SIZE_IOT` defined using `#define` - how can I use it? ( pre-processor won't pass `extern`)

Comment: @Guy.D You can't `extern` to a different type. If you want to have something else then give yourself a pointer to it and do a cast to that pre-defined object.